# Can I say "Reduce costs by up to 50% less"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

I want to talk about an achievement and say that sometimes costs are reduced by 20%, sometimes by 50%.

> I created a solution to reduce costs by up to 50% less.

How should I phrase this?

Comment: **I created a solution to reduce costs by up to 50%.** Don't need the `less` at the end.

Comment: **With my solution costs are up to 50% less.**  I agree with @d.b ... do not include both "reduce" and "less".

Comment: @GEdgar: "50% less" doesn't sound right at all. I would expect "50% lower".

Comment: OP, if you said the sentence as it stands, whomever heard it would think that your plan achieved 50% less savings than some other plan.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is not correct. The reason is because “reduce” and “less” both refer to reduction, so it is unclear whether you are unnecessarily stating the reduction twice, or making a reduction to the reduction - which is confusing either way.

Your sentence would work by removing “less.” Then you would only refer to the reduction once, which is your intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you correctly use the phrase

> costs reduced by 20%, sometimes by 50%

You don't need the word "less" and the word "reduce".  You don't say "costs reduced by 20% less"

And you don't need the word "less" in your original phrase:

> I created a solution to reduce costs by up to 50%.

There are other ways to phrase this, some of which have already been given in comments

Answer (score 0):

The word **less** makes it incorrect.

> I created a solution to reduce costs by up to 50%.

If you know the correct range is 20-50, it's often better to be specific and say that. Otherwise "up to 50%" might be perceived as intentionally misleading.

> I created a solution to reduce costs by 20% to 50%.